# How and where to save image after user selects an image in app: Android

Tags: android, imageview, uri

I have a tab for which i let the user select an image from the Gallery or by taking a new photo. Once I get the Uri, I display that image in the respective tab.

But, I want to make sure that the image is still there with when the user comes back to the app. 
Now one option is that i save the uri and then when the app is loaded again, I display the image based on the Uri, as was done when the user initially selected the photo. 
The issue with this approach is that I only have the Uri in the app for the image. So if the user deletes that photo from his gallery then i will have nothing to show.

So is there a way to store that image in my app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use one of the storing ways that android provides:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Saving in External Storage or SD Card is one of the best options.